# Optimization for tank

Tags: calculus, optimization

I need to design a tube that will hold 300 liters of water. The shape of the tube is a cylinder with a sphere on each end. The cylinder part costs 10 cents per  cm^2 to make while the spheres cost 30 cents per  cm^2  to make. What is the radius of the tube that will minimize the cost? I need to find the optimal radius please.! I know the volume of a cylinder is (pi)(r^2)(h), and the volume of a sphere is (4/3)(pi)(r^3). There are two spheres so that will be doubled

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LJcv.jpg)

Comment: What are the formulas for the volume of a cylinder and the surfaces of a cylinder and a sphere ? They can be googled.

Comment: I have gotten that far but I am unsure on how to find the optimal radius

Comment: Ok then make an edit of your question and add the formulas. We want to see want you have tried. Were you able to formulate the condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The volume is:
$V=($Volume of two emispher of radius $r)+($Volume of a cylinder of radius $r$ and height $h)=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3+\pi r^2h$

From that equation you can find $h(r)$: the height as a function of $r$ .

Now write  the cost function as:

$C(r)=30 \cdot($Area of the two semispheres$ )+10\cdot ($lateral Area of the cylinder$)=$ $ 30\cdot 4 \pi r^2+10\cdot 2\pi r h(r)$.

This the function of $r$ that you want minimize.